# How return View with model in the ExceptionFilter in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created an Asp.Net Core MVC application. I want to handle two types of errors.

I have create two exceptions: `UserFriendlyException` and `UserFriendlyViewException`.

I have tried to create the `ExceptionFilter` that I need handle these two exceptions according these rules:

If is exception `UserFriendlyViewException` called then I want to return ViewResult with original ViewName and `AddModelError` and return original Model.

If is exception `UserFriendlyException` called then I want to redirect to `Error` view.

This is my `ExceptionFilterAttribute`:

```cs
public class ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;
    private readonly IModelMetadataProvider _modelMetadataProvider;

    public ControllerExceptionFilterAttribute(ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory,
                IModelMetadataProvider modelMetadataProvider)
    {
        _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        _modelMetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider;
    }
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (!(context.Exception is UserFriendlyException) && !(context.Exception is UserFriendlyViewException)) return;

        var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context.HttpContext);
        //CreateNotification(NotificationHelpers.AlertType.Error, tempData, context.Exception.Message);
        if (!tempData.ContainsKey(NotificationHelpers.NotificationKey)) return;

        if (context.Exception is UserFriendlyViewException userFriendlyViewException)
        {
            context.ModelState.AddModelError(userFriendlyViewException.ErrorKey, userFriendlyViewException.Message);
        }

        if (context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
        {
            //How pass here Model from context??
            //If exists more views with same name but in another controller how pass correct ViewName?
            var result = new ViewResult
            {
                ViewName = context.Exception is UserFriendlyViewException ?
                controllerActionDescriptor.ActionName
                : "Error",
                TempData = tempData,
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(_modelMetadataProvider, context.ModelState)
                            {
                                {"Notifications", tempData[NotificationHelpers.NotificationKey] },
                            }
            };

            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
            context.Result = result;
        }

        tempData.Remove(NotificationHelpers.NotificationKey);
    }
}
```

I have two issues:

1.) How can I pass original `Model` from `ExceptionContext` to `ViewResult`?

2.) How return correct ViewName for `UserFriendlyViewException` if exists more Views with same name but in another Controller?

Comment: Able to achieve to get the model bind in view?

Answer (score 1):

***How can I pass original Model from ExceptionContext to ViewResult?***

You may use `context.ModelState` collection.

```
 foreach(var item in context.ModelState)
 {
    string parameter = item.Key;
    object rawValue = item.Value.RawValue;
    string attemptedValue = item.Value.AttemptedValue;

    System.Console.WriteLine($"Parameter: {parameter}, value: {attemptedValue}");
 }
```

Note, collection will contain only bound parameters.

---

***How return correct ViewName for UserFriendlyViewException if exists more Views with same name but in another Controller?***

The same [View discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview) process will be used by framework as in the controller's action, so instead of View name you can specify the path:

> A view file path can be provided instead of a view name. If using an absolute path starting at the app root (optionally starting with "/" or "~/"), the .cshtml extension must be specified:
>
> ```
> return View("Views/Home/About.cshtml");
> ```
>
> You can also use a relative path to specify views in different directories without the .cshtml extension. Inside the HomeController, you can return the Index view of your Manage views with a relative path:
>
> ```
> return View("../Manage/Index");
> ```
>
> Similarly, you can indicate the current controller-specific directory with the "./" prefix:
>
> ```
> return View("./About");
> ```

Comment: Can you show how the ModelState use in the ViewResult in your sample code, please?

Comment: @Jenan sorry that was not clear - my point is that you can construct custom model using data from `context.ModelState`

Comment: OK, is it possible to construct original model what was passed in controller action? Or is it necessary create some customization of model? Thank you for clarification.

Comment: I think it depends on your View actually, as it consumes the passed model

Comment: I am wondering about passing the original model as the param in UserFriendlyViewException and read it from it? What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

Pass stuff via ViewData

```
public class UIFriendlyExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is UIFriendlyException uex)
        {
            var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), context.ModelState);

            //here we go
            viewData.Add("Message", MY_CUSTOM_MESSAGE);

            var res = new ViewResult() {
                ViewName = "Error",
                ViewData = viewData
            };
            context.Result = res;
        }
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Then register in Startup

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{ 
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(UIFriendlyException.UIFriendlyExceptionFilter));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepare two Filters.
One caches the Binding Model and the other handles exceptions.

IActionFilter

```
public class BindModelCacheFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public static readonly string Key = "BindModelCacheFilterKey. This string can be anything.";

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Items[BindModelCacheFilter.Key] = context.ActionArguments;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

IExceptionFilter

```
public class ExceptionHandlingFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger<ExceptionHandlingFilter> _logger;

    public ExceptionHandlingFilter(ILogger<ExceptionHandlingFilter> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // ...

            var requestPayload = "";
            try
            {
                var actionArguments = context.HttpContext.Items[BindModelCacheFilter.Key] as IDictionary<string, object?>;
                if (0 < actionArguments?.Count)
                {
                    object requestDto = actionArguments.First().Value!;
                    var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions()
                    {
                        IncludeFields = true,
                        Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.Create(System.Text.Unicode.UnicodeRanges.All)
                    };
                    requestPayload = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestDto, options);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an ExceptionFilter that derives both from IExceptionFilter, IActionFilter

This gives you access to the view and the controller

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(ExceptionFilter))]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    public IActionResult SomeAction([Bind("ID")] MyView vm) {}
}

public class ExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter, IActionFilter
{
    private MyController? MyController { get; set; }
    private MyViewModel vm { get; set; }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        MyController = (MyController)context.Controller;
        //
        if (context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("vm", out object vmObj))            
           vm = vmObj as MyView;
        else
           vm = null;

    }

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        // Do something using MyController and MyView
    }
}
```